# An error is issued when opening the telebot keyboard

Tags: python, api, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

There is such a code, it opens the keyboard after changing the message, but an error is issued when executing.

```
elif (merchant_id == 2):
                bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text='Your request was accepted', parse_mode="Markdown", reply_markup=keyboard.main_keyboard())
```

Error:

> A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: inline keyboard expected

But when executing another part of the code, the keyboard opens immediately. Here is the keyboard code:

```
def main_keyboard():
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard = False, resize_keyboard = True)
btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('Hello')
btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Start')
btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('Add')
btn4 = types.KeyboardButton('Stop')
markup.add(btn1, btn3)
markup.add(btn2)
markup.add(btn4)
return markup
```

How to solve the problem so that the keyboard opens correctly in both parts of the code ?
Maybe it is necessary to replace or add some functionality.

Answer (score 0):

`main_keyboard` returns a `ReplyKeyboardMarkup`, but the `reply_markup` parameter `edit_message_text` only accepts `InlineKeyboardMarkup` objects as explained in the [official API docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagetext). In the header of the ["updating messages" paragraph](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#updating-messages) it says:

> Please note, that it is currently only possible to edit messages without reply_markup or with inline keyboards.